# How to iterate over each members of an object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have an object from a third party REST API. What I want to do is to iterate over each members of the object and get its key and value. The format of the object is like this :

```
 { 1st:"1", 2nd: "2", 3rd: "3rd" }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's as simple as

```
hash = { ... } # result from api call

hash.each do |key, value|
  # do your thing here
end
```

BTW, in ruby it's called "a hash", not "an object".

Comment: is the OP's hash valid?

Comment: good point @sagarpandya82 - am assuming that's just an example and the keys don't actually begin numbers?

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Comment: @mikej ah yes that makes sense.